# Flask threads share values

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, redis, sse

I have a Flask application which extracts data, then it transforms that data and those results are then uploaded to a data repo.  These series of steps I want to 'log' to the Web UI, and if needed, log also the warnings.

In the same Flask application, I implemented SSE (server sent events) and it works, yet I have not been able to 'update' the events to reflect the state of the application.  Can some one point me as to how I can 'share' the data between the SSE that continually updates the browser and the running application so as to keep the user updated on the data processing? Or maybe a different approach?  All ideas are welcomed. I'm new to Flask.

This is the views.py module where the UI resides:

```
from flask import render_template
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def index():
    """ User Interface page """
    return render_template('index.html')
```

The index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Status</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/sse.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Status</h1>
        <div id="status"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The sse.js is here:

```
var sse = new EventSource('/status');
sse.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = e.data;
};
```

Here is the SSE code itself:

```
class ServerSentEvents(object):

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.event = None
        self.id = None
        self.desc_map = {
            'data': self.data,
            'event': self.event,
            'id': self.id}

    def encode(self):
        if not self.data:
            return ''

        lines = ['{}: {}'.format(k, v) for k, v in self.desc_map.items() if v]
        return '{}\n\n'.format('\n'.join(lines))
```

The status implementation with Redis:

```
from flask import Response
from .sse import ServerSentEvents
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class EntityStatus():
    """ Broadcast application state """

    def __init__(self, red):
        self.red = red

    def status(self):

        def ready():
            pubsub = self.red.pubsub()
            pubsub.subscribe('status')
            for message in pubsub.listen():
                logger.debug('Status: {}'.format(message['data']))
                ev = ServerSentEvents(message['data'])
                yield ev.encode()

        return Response(ready(), mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

Here is the routing module:

```
from .version import __version__
from .actions import index
from .actions import EntityStatus


def add_routes(app, red, etl):

    def _add_headers(response):
        """ Add custom response headers """
        response.headers['X-App-Version'] = __version__
        response.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Segments Engine'
        return response

    app.after_request(_add_headers)

    api = EntityStatus(red)

    app.add_url_rule('/', 'index', index)
    app.add_url_rule('/status', 'status', api.status)
    app.add_url_rule('/etl', 'etl', etl.etl)
```

And here an extract of the code where the status is sent:

```
class EntityApi(object):
    """ Entity API """

    def __init__(self, debug, red, data):
        self.debug = debug
        self.red = red

        self.red.publish('status', 'API Ready')
```

The 'index' page loads a js script which successfully points and receives the SSE data from the server and displays the data properly. 'status' is where the data is sent from, and 'etl' is where the actual data processing is taking place.

Comment: Will `etl` view function handle more than one requests at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code you are looking at now. Using Redis and SSE I have now managed to publish to Web UI the update in the application status when it is crunching data :) The Notification examples I found and other related Redis and Celery implementations helped me get to this point, thank you everyone :) I just needed a simple solution that can later be improved and scaled from here.